# The two-current model of superconductivity

Tags: superconductivity, superfluidity

Standard text books (Landau and Lifshitz etc) explain that the correct macroscopic theory of a superfluid is two-fluid hydrodynamics. A superfluid is made of two components, a viscous normal fluid and a non-viscous superfluid. The total current is the sum of normal and superfluid contributions, and in thermal equilibrium the density of the normal component is not zero. This picture is supported by microscopic theories, and by many experiments, most notably the observation of second sound.

Then, presumably, the correct theory of a current carrying superconductor is the two current theory. Again, in equilibrium the density of the normal component is not zero, and a generic current should always contain both components. Why do we (almost) never discuss this theory? Is the resistivity of the normal component so large that it is quickly dissipated away? Or is the normal density typically too low to be relevant? Where is the second sound mode? (Is it screened? Or damped?)

As a corollary, what is the right way to think about a persistent current in a superconducting loop? After some time, the normal current is presumably dissipated away. Does that mean that the supercurrent state is not in thermal equilibrium? If yes, why does it persist? (Is it meta-stable?)

Answer (score 3):

If we have a circuit with a resistor $R$ Ohms  in parallel with an $R=0$  resistor, all the current will flow through the zero resistance branch. This is what happens in a superconductor --- the supercurrent short circuits any  normal current that might otherwise be carried by thermally excited quasiparticles. I expect this is what you mean by "is dissipated away", so your supposition is correct.

Even at zero temperature, however, if the frequency is such that $\hbar \omega> 2\Delta_{\rm gap}$ quasiparticles will be excited and dissipation will heat the system. In this case we can think of the heating as being due to  a normal current.

Comment: If this argument is correct, then why does it not apply to a superfluid? It would show that the normal current is always zero, and the two-fluid theory is irrelevant.

Comment: @Thomas  When  superfluid $^4$He flows through a microleak (the anlogue of a supercurrent in a wire) only the supercurrent  is present.  The main difference with the superconductor is that there is no energy gap in superfluid $^4$He, so at finite temperature there are lots of phonons about. They can be driven by applying heat to get the fountain effect or to tranport mass (i.e the normal current). In superconductor, the energy gap means very  few quasiparticles (the normal component)  and fewer dramatic effects -- although there are some.

Comment: 1) I think it is possible that the main difference is just the density of the normal component (big in Helium, small in superconductors). I'm unconvinced, however, because these days we have fermionic superfluids (ultracold gases, for example) with a big gap that are well described by two-fluid hydro.

Comment: 2) I am also unconvinced by the superleak example. The analog of a persistent current would be superflow in a wide channel. Why doesn't the superfluid separate from the normal fluid and "short circuit" the flow as you write in your answer?

Comment: @Thomas: I forgot what is  perhaps the main point. The normal component (phonons) in $^4$He feels friction only from scattering off  the walls of the container, so  feels  little friction in a wide pipe. In a narrow superleak the phonons are  equilibrium with the walls  and their momentum, being   opposed to the $\rho_{\rm tot}v$ condensate flow reduces the mass flow. i.e  the normal component does not flow. In a solid superconductor the quasiparticle normal component feels friction from scattering off impurities throughout the material so even in a wide conductor there is no "normal" current.

Comment: I don't think that's right: The whole point of the two-fluid theory is that the normal component is viscous. Landau computed the viscosity of the normal component, and it smoothly matches the viscosity of normal liquid helium. Viscosity of the normal fluid damps second sound, and dissipates energy.

Comment: However, I think that your general suspicion must be right. The only reasonable explanation I can think of (for why there is no second sound etc in superconductors) is that in some suitable sense the resistance of the normal current is bigger than the viscosity of the normal fluid in helium.

Answer (score 2):

I will make a lame attempt to answer my own question. I found a paper by Jim Bardeen titled ``Two fluid model of superconductivity'', Phys.Rev.Lett. 11, 399 (1958). Bardeen states

> *Because of the very high attenuation of the normal component from interaction with the crystal lattice, phenomena such as second sound
> would be difficult to observe in superconductors.*

Unfortunately, Bardeen does not really explain what this statement is based on.
Note that if the damping of these modes behaves like collisional damping of MHD modes,  $\gamma\sim\jmath^2/\sigma$, then the problem is that the conductivity is too low, and second sound modes would be easier to observe in a dirty superconductor.

Bardeen does indeed state that the free energy goes as
$$
 F = \frac{\jmath_s^2}{\rho_s} + \frac{\jmath_n^2}{\rho_n} 
$$
where $\jmath=\jmath_n+\jmath_s$ are the normal and superfluid components of the current, and $\rho_n$, $\rho_s$ the associated densities. This clearly shows that in equilibrium both components must be present (if the free energy is minimized with $\jmath=\jmath_n+\jmath_s$ fixed, then both $\jmath_n$ and $\jmath_s$ are non-zero).

This means that a persistent supercurrent is not an equilibrium state. It should be possible to estimate the barrier for the decay of the supercurrent
states, based on flux quantization and the expression for the free energy, but I have not tried to put in realistic numbers.

Comment: What Bardeen means in his quote is the following. In a superfluid, second sound consists of the normal and superfluid fraction moving out-of-phase so that there is no mass transport. In a superconductor, the normal fluid component will have friction, which will prevent second sound from being observed. You are also correct about persistent currents

Comment: @Xcheckr Second sound in an superfluid is also damped by friction (viscosity) of the normal component. I think that the difference between a superfluid and a superconductor must be quantitative rather than qualitative.

Comment: You are right that it is quantitative. In the superconductor, there are phonons, impurities, etc. that damp the normal fluid and the mean free path for the electrons are much shorter. In liquid helium, the particles can flow much easier (mean free path is much longer) and therefore the fluids can actually oscillate out of phase to set up second sound propagation.

Comment: @Xcheckr Note that large mean free path implies large viscosity, which implies strong damping (not weak damping).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that comment? Taking the limit of very large mean free path means effectively no scattering and therefore no damping...

Comment: @Xcheckr Viscosity is counterintuitive, $\eta\sim l_{mfp}$, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#Viscosity_and_kinetic_momentum

Comment: Also note that second sound is a collisional mode

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Regardless, the point is that in a liquid, the normal fluid can "flow" whereas the normal electrons in a metal cannot "flow" as easily. This is ultimately what prevents the second sound mode from being observed in a superconductor.